# Browser Detection in HttpModule

Tags: browser, httpmodule

Is there a way to detect what browser the request is made in the HttpModule?

Thanks.

Comment: browser sniffing is generally discouraged. care to explain why you want access to it?

Comment: I developing an HTTPModule to figure out if the user is browsing from a mobile browser and if so generate only text-only content for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class TestModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.Request.Browser....;
    }
}
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser(VS.80).aspx)